# Were there ever plans for a "Bastard!" TV series in Japan?

Tags: bastard

Bastard! Is one of my favorite OVA series, and I've even read some of the manga. From what I can gather, an OVA series is either a precursor to or a result of a TV series of lower quality. Was there ever a plan to make such a series based on the manga?

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3806/what-happened-to-the-last-two-bastard-ovas might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only those involved will know if it was ever intended to have a tv release, but I imagine it probably was initially aiming for such.

After testing the waters with the OVAs, they presumably didn't move forward with any plans to that extent as the OVAs did very badly and didn't even finish production.